# Can't find Linq to SQL Classes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2019

I installed the Linq to SQL tools but options like "LINQ to SQL classes " are not showing. Can anyone help me please.

[image: Installation checked]

[image: Options not showing]

I'm using the Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I tried it but i didn't work, when I try to a new Item to the project the Option : "LINQ to SQL Classes " doesnt show up

Comment: Looks like it is no longer possible to create a new .dbml file, you must create one in an older VS version-

Comment: I’ll try that thank you